# assert inside if else condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, assert, assertion

I want to check the following using `assert`.

If: key `mean` is in dictionary `d` then it should have length equal to `N`.
else: `sigma` should not be `None`.

What is the concise and pythonic way to write this assertion?

I tried this:

```
if "mean" in d:
    assert len(d["mean"]) == N
else:
    assert sigma is not None
```

Comment: Did you try any particular way of writing it? Did you find something unsatisfactory about your way of writing it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is what I have in mind (updated the question)

Comment: This looks fine to me. You could reduce it to a single `assert` statement using a conditional expression to choose which comparison to assert, but it would be less readable. (`assert len(...) == N if mean in d else sigma is not None`)

Comment: That's a typo; it should be `... if 'mean' in d else ...`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator help?

Comment: The Pythonic way is to not use assert at all. The assert should be used to validate algorithm correctness, or used in unit tests. It should not be used to validate input data.

Comment: @Keith Where do they say that it's input data?

Comment: @KellyBundy I inferred from the code structure. You can't remove those assertions and keep working, meaningful code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more code style thing, but if you want it to read like "it has one assert", I'd suggest:

```py
has_expected_mean_len = 'mean' in d and len(d['mean']) == N
has_sigma = 'mean' not in d and sigma is not None

assert has_expected_mean_len or has_sigma
```